# How to find the function that is run after cursor is moved?

Tags: debugging

I am working with a highly customized emacs configuration that is not built by me and it highlights all the words in the buffer that match the word under the cursor.

How to find the function that highlights all the words under the cursor?

After the key sequence **forward-word**, **backward-word** or **down-mouse-1** the highlight occurs. There are no hooks set up for these key sequences.

It appears there is a small delay after the cursor move ends and the highlight occurs.

Are there any cursor or timer hooks that can be examined to find the function that highlights the words under the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

I know 2 packages for highlighting symbol under curser.

- [symbol-overlay](https://github.com/wolray/symbol-overlay)
- [highlight-symbol](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el) which is older and inspired the first

Both of them use the same hook: [`post-command-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Overview.html), see [`symbol-overlay-mode`](https://github.com/wolray/symbol-overlay/blob/master/symbol-overlay.el#L223) and [`highlight-symbol-mode`](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/blob/master/highlight-symbol.el#L204)

Both of them use [timers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html).